# Equating and solving equations that have been generated using table[]

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, replacement, list-manipulation

I am in the process of trying to use Mathematica to find the coefficients of transmission and reflection for the wavefunction of a beam of particles tunnelling across any number of identical potential barriers.

I have got to the stage where  I am able to generate the equations for n numbers of barriers, but I am not able to equate the appropriate equations to each other to solve them for the coefficients. The module I have written to generate the relavant equations is:

```
GeneratePhiEqs[N_] :=
    Module[{inceqs, diffinceqs, bareqs, diffbareqs, finaleq, difffinaleq,
    IncidentPhi, BarrierPhi, FinalTransmittedPhi, phieqs}, 
    IncidentPhi[x_, n_] := T[n]*E^(I*k*x) + R[n]*E^(-I*k*x);
    BarrierPhi[x_, n_] := A[n]*E^(r*x) + B[n]*E^(-r*x);
    FinalTransmittedPhi[x_, n_] := T[n]*E^(I*k*x); T[0] = 1;

    inceqs = Table[Phi[j] = {IncidentPhi[x, j]}, {j, 0, N}];
    diffinceqs = 
    Table[Phi[N + j] = {D[IncidentPhi[x, j], x]}, {j, 0, N - 1}];
    bareqs = Table[Phi[2 N + j - 1] = {BarrierPhi[x, j]}, {j, N}];
    diffbareqs = 
    Table[Phi[3 N + j - 1] = {D[BarrierPhi[x, j], x]}, {j, N}];
    finaleq = Phi[4 N] = FinalTransmittedPhi[ x, N];
    difffinaleq = Phi[4 N + 1] = D[FinalTransmittedPhi[x, N], x];
    phieqs = {inceqs, diffinceqs, bareqs, diffbareqs, finaleq, 
    difffinaleq}; phieqs]
```

The module I have written (or what it looks like so far) to equate the relevant equations is:

```
SolvePhiEqs[number_] := 
    Module[{eqs, simeqs}, eqs = GeneratePhiEqs[number]; 
    simeqs = Table[{Phi[j] /. phieqs == Phi[2*number + j] /. 
    phieqs}, {j, 2*number - 1}]; simeqs]
```

Basically, the equations that I generated with the first module will not substitute in correctly, they just remain isolated from each other surrounded by curly brackets.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: I get a collection of stuff by running `GeneratePhiEqs[1]`. But these are not equations, yet, they have no equality. Can you explain what terms are to be equated with what?

Comment: Can you write what explicitly **A[n], B[n], R[n], T[n]** are? Also, the usage **Table[Phi[j] = {IncidentPhi[x, j]}, {j, 0, N}]** looks so weird to me. I would rather go with something much simpler like **Phi[j_]:={IncidentPhi[x, j]}**.

Comment: @bills GeneratePhiEqs effectively gives me a set of functions and their derivatives, some of which I know are equal to each other at a certain value of x. I need to equate particular functions to each other and substitute in a value for x in order to solve for the coefficients. The SolvePhiEqs module should take care of equating them to each other and solving them.

Comment: In answer to your question @Ali the A[n], B[n] are coefficients. For example, if I run GeneratePhiEqs[1], I get a certain number of equations, and it numbers the coefficients for me. I am trying to solve for the coefficients.

Comment: I get a function like $e^{ikx}$ at one barrier, but then I get the same thing at another barrier. I want to differentiate between them whilst still being able to see that they are related.

Comment: `GeneratePhiEqs[1]` gives a list of 6 items, the first one has 2 subitems. Which of these are to be equated to which? The reason I ask is because `SolvePhiEqs[1]` is syntactically incorrect, and so I cannot figure out what terms you wish to equate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly this?

```
Clear[Phi];
GeneratePhiEqs[N_] := (* <- Don't use N *)
 Module[{inceqs, diffinceqs, bareqs, diffbareqs, finaleq, difffinaleq,
    IncidentPhi, BarrierPhi, FinalTransmittedPhi}, 
  IncidentPhi[x_, n_] := T[n]*E^(I*k*x) + R[n]*E^(-I*k*x);
  BarrierPhi[x_, n_] := A[n]*E^(r*x) + B[n]*E^(-r*x);
  FinalTransmittedPhi[x_, n_] := T[n]*E^(I*k*x); T[0] = 1;
  inceqs      = Table[Phi[j] -> IncidentPhi[x, j], {j, 0, N}];
  diffinceqs  = Table[Phi[N + j] -> D[IncidentPhi[x, j], x], {j, 0, N - 1}];
  bareqs      = Table[Phi[2 N + j - 1] -> BarrierPhi[x, j], {j, N}];
  diffbareqs  = Table[Phi[3 N + j - 1] -> D[BarrierPhi[x, j], x], {j, N}];
  finaleq     = Phi[4 N] -> FinalTransmittedPhi[x, N];
  difffinaleq = Phi[4 N + 1] -> D[FinalTransmittedPhi[x, N], x];
  Flatten @ {inceqs, diffinceqs, bareqs, diffbareqs, finaleq, difffinaleq}]

SolvePhiEqs[number_] := 
 Module[{eqs},
  eqs = GeneratePhiEqs[number];
  Table[Phi[j] == Phi[2*number + j] /. eqs, {j, 2*number - 1}]
 ]
```

If it's right, then you should

- generate replacement [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html)s (`->`) with `GeneratePhiEqs` instead of setting `Phi[..]` equal to something;
- drop the extra braces;
- use just one [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) and note the precedence of the operator `/.`;
- [avoid starting your variables/functions with capital letters](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395) -- [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html) is a *Mathematica* function;
- [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) returns the value of the last expression so I omitted a couple of variables.

Example:

```
SolvePhiEqs[2]
(* {E^(-I k x) R[1] + E^(I k x) T[1] == E^(r x) A[2] + E^(-r x) B[2], 
    E^(-I k x) R[2] + E^(I k x) T[2] == E^(r x) r A[1] - E^(-r x) r B[1],
    -I E^(-I k x) k R[1] + I E^(I k x) k T[1] == E^(r x) r A[2] - E^(-r x) r B[2]} *)
```

Comment: It works - Thank you so much! Please excuse my cobbled together syntax, I'm a bit of a Mathematica beginner.